# PayPal ConvertCurrency Service what does conversionType do?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've been running through some samples with PayPals ConvertCurrency service (part of AdaptivePayments), and don't understand what the `conversionType` is meant to do?

The default value is `SENDER_SIDE`, and as I understand it is basically saying: "If I send $100, this will be received as £61.42". This works fine and makes sense.

If I switch it to `RECEIVER_SIDE` I thought it would be saying: "If I want to receive $100, then £??? would need to be sent". But the number it gives is exactly the same - which I don't understand at all!

Can someone explain what that parameter does, or is it broken on sandbox?

Thanks

Matt